# How do we use a JSON result from $http.get in Angular?

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm getting a json using $http.$get, but to it be "compatible" with Angular, I'm having to convert it this way:

```
$http.get('/api/v1.0/plans').
    success(function(data) {
        var plans = [];

        for(var propertyName in data)
        {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(propertyName))
            {
                plans.push(data[propertyName]);
            }
        }

        $scope.plans = angular.fromJson(data);
    });
```

But, of course, I think this would be the way to go in this case, as shown in docs:

```
$http.get('/api/v1.0/plans').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.plans = data;
    });
```

I can see the difference between the objects, I just don't know how to fix it:

#### data (not accepted by angular)

```
Object {alfa: Object, beta: Object, delta: Object, omega: Object}
```

#### plans (converted and accepted by angular)

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Could you, please, tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem isn't with JSON, in the first case `$scope.plans` is an object, in the second case it is an array. An object represents unstructured key value collection or a "thing", an array is a sequence of things. By the way - an object is unordered and different browsers will order the array differently. Consider reading about arrays and objects in either "Eloquent JavaScript" (free) or MDN.

Comment: Here is a reference: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html . Seeing your background is in PHP - JS arrays are different. In PHP arrays are associative. In JS arrays are sequential by nature with a `.length` that only cares about their (numerically) indexed properties. You can't feed an object directly to `ng-repeat` for instance, you can however do `ng-repeat="(name, value) in plans"` as special syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to elaborate a bit more about what kind of "compatible" problem you refered to in your first sentence. As far as I know, both JSON representations work just fine in Angular for me.

I believe the question here boils down to how the data will be used after being set to `$scope.plans`. If you are trying to use `ng-repeat` with `$scope.plans` afterward, then how you iterate will differ slightly depending whether the data you receive is a JSON object or JSON array.

For JSON object, you use

```
<tr ng-repeat="(name, plan) in plans">
    <td> {{name}} </td> <td> {{ plan | json }} </td>
</tr>
```

For JSON array, you use

```
<tr ng-repeat="plan in plans">
    <td> {{$index}} </td> <td> {{ plan | json }} </td>
</tr>
```

Of course, for `plan` specified in HTML snippets above, you can access object inner fields with dot notation as usual (i.e., `{{plan.title}}`, `{{plan.description}}`, etc.). `{{plan | json}}` just converts JSON object into string so you can see object content directly in HTML.

For details on how to use `ngRepeat`, you can read more at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

In case a (Object {alfa: Object, beta: Object, delta: Object, omega: Object} your api return object so you have to define plans as a object not array that should works

```
$scope.plans = {}; // <-object
$http.get('/api/v1.0/plans').
    success(function(data) {

       angular.copy(data, $scope.plans);  
    });
```

in case you api will return array of object you have to define plans as a array ie:

```
$scope.plans = []; // <-array
$http.get('/api/v1.0/plans').
    success(function(data) {

       angular.copy(data, $scope.plans);  
    });
```

Please see bin [here](http://jsbin.com/jawox/1/)

Comment: I've added link to bin in answer.